# How to Run a TFX Orchestration Pipeline Outside Jupyter?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, tfx

Learning data ingestion and prediction orchestration with tensorflow from this [notebook on github](https://github.com/Building-ML-Pipelines/building-machine-learning-pipelines/blob/main/chapters/adv_tfx/Custom_TFX_Components.ipynb). It is using an `InteractiveContext` on the ipython environment. But obviously a production system does not run ipython. When I try to run the code in REPL python shell, I get

```
WARNING:absl:Method "run" is a no-op when invoked outside of IPython.
```

So how to run the orchestration outside a jupyter notebook, as a simple python script. Also, what other modification necessary to run the pipeline in real production environment?